# Is there a way to make the entire combobox clickable in a windows form?

Tags: winforms, combobox, drop-down-menu, clickable

Instead of only the little tiny down arrow? Seems like there should be a property I can set or something, but I'm not seeing one... unless I'm blind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

maybe? That will make the combo box non-editable, i.e. it won't act like a text box with a button but just as a large button that will open the drop-down.

Comment: Yup, that's it! lol, can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Johann: Most of that time was spent finding that damn property again. It's been over 1½ years since I've done Winforms stuff ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the combobox DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList, it will be automatic